# Lipschitz continuity of atomless measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lipschitz continuous in the first argument, i.e. there exists $L \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $\sup_{w \in \mathbb{R}^m} | f(x,w)-f(y,w) | \leq L |x-y|$.

Let $m: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m) \rightarrow [0,1]$ be an *atomless* probability measure. Assume $f$ is measurable.

I am wondering under what additonal conditions the following holds.

For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have

$$ \left| m\left( \left\{ w \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid f( x ,w  ) > 0  \right\} \right) - m\left( \left\{ w \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid f( y ,w  ) > 0  \right\} \right) \right| \leq L |x-y| $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I understand the necessity of the *atomless* assumption, but it does not get you anything quantitative (e.g., Lipschitz continuity). You have to somehow rule out absolutely continuous measures that approximate a point mass.
2. More precisely, you need a *strong, quantitative* assumption linking the Euclidean metric and the measure $m$. Something like Ahlfors $Q$-regularity: $c r^Q \le m(B(x,r))\le Cr^Q$ with $c,C,Q$ independent of $x,r$.
3. In order to have Lipschitz continuity of upper level sets in variable $w$, you need a  *reverse* Lipschitz condition with respect to $w$. Consider the special case $f(x,w)=F(w)-x$ and the Lebesgue measure (in one dimension, to simplify things). You will see that the Lipschitz continuity of $m(\{w:F(w)>x\})$ holds if $|F'|\ge \epsilon>0$  and fails if $F'$ vanishes somewhere, e.g., $F(x)=x^3$ on $[-1,1]$. In higher dimension (still for the Lebesgue measure) you need $|\nabla F|\ge \epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps you may also help me here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419566/strictly-monotone-probability-measure. I am thinking about Ahlfors $\mathcal{Q}$-regularity also there.