# Strictly monotone probability measure

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $m$ be a probability measure on $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable.

Assume that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such $m\left( \{ x \in X \mid |f'(x)| \leq \epsilon \}\right) = 0$, that is, $f$ is almost flat on a set of measure $0$.

Under what conditions, for all $\alpha\geq 0$, the following inequality holds?

$$ m\left( \left\{ x \in X \mid f(x) > 0 \right\} \right) +  \epsilon \alpha \leq m\left( \left\{ x \in X \mid \sup_{ y \in \{x\}+\alpha \mathbb{B} }  f(y) > 0 \right\} \right) $$

Prove it.

Comment. I think it is interesting to see whether maximizing $f$ locally implies a strict increase on the value of the probability. I do not know under what conditions I could put the $\epsilon\alpha$ outside.

Hint. I started with $m[\sup_{y \in \{x\} +\alpha \mathbb{B}} f(y)>0 ] \geq m[ f(x) + \epsilon \alpha >0 ]$