# On continuity of measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $m$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider a function $\ f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Say under what conditions the following inequality holds.
$$ m\left(\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m : \sup_{ y \in \{x\} + \epsilon \mathbb{B} }  f(y) >0 \right\} \right) \ \leq \ m\left(\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m : \ f(x) >0 \right\} \right) + g(\epsilon) $$
for some strictly increasing $g: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $g(0) = 0$.

Comments. I think that at least $m$ has to be atomless.

This question is similar to [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417679/lipschitz-continuity-of-atomless-measures).

Comment: $f$ need not be continuous. Consider $f$ the characteristic function of a ball, and $m$ the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you also have an idea on how to address the all question?

Comment: Not really, with $P_f =\{x\colon f(x) > 0\}$, the inequality is more succinctly written $m\bigl(B_\varepsilon(P_f)\bigr)\leqslant m(P_f) + g(\varepsilon)$. Now the question is, what are the things that are given? If you can freely choose all three, $m,\, f,\, g$, I don't think you can say much. If $m$ is given, the question which $f$ satisfy the inequality for a given $g$ may be interesting. But I think most interesting would be "which $m$ allow such an inequality for all $f\in C$ with a given $g$", where $C$ is an interesting class of functions. Or you could change the roles of $f$ and $m$.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the comments. I think the question is like: which $m$'s and $g$'s allow such an inequality for all (continuous) $f$?